# Robustness checks for Pooled OLS, Fixed Effects, and GMM

Tags: r, panel-data, convergence, fixed-effects-model, generalized-moments

I am investigating **conditional convergence** across Indian states using panel data.  I include the state name, year, SDP per capita, and a number of conditioning variables such as Public Expenditure, Literacy, Rural Banks per Capita.  I hypothesize that I will find weak evidence of conditional convergence when controlling for some of the production fundamentals of each state.

I wanted to check that I have done the correct robustness checks for my model.  I am using R, and the **plm** package in particular.  The conditional convergence regression will include a specification with a **pooled OLS and controlling variables**, a specification with **state fixed effects and controlling variables**, and a specification with **state fixed effects as well as time fixed effects and controlling variables**.

- I attempted to do a **Hausman test** for fixed vs. random effects, but it was unsuccessful as I believe my regressors are too dependent.
- I did a **Breusch-Pagan test** for heteroskedasticity
- I also used the **Ramsey RESE**T test for functional form.
- I will be using **SEs clustere**d at the state level.

Are there any R tests I am missing for pooled OLS and state/time fixed effects?  What assumptions have I left out?

I also was interested in adding a more sophisticated specification: the **GMM model**.  I found in the literature that OLS estimates are inconsistent (biased upwards) in the presence of a lagged dependent variable and fixed effects.  GMM was used in a number of the papers I read, but I dismissed it initially.  Then I started to think that including a lagged growth rate variable would be prudent. The plm package appears to support GMM models.

I understand that the GMM estimator allows past realizations of the dependent variable to affects its current value, and I think it would add a lot of value, but I am unsure of the assumptions/robustness tests I need to perform.  If it is relatively straightforward I would like to move forward with it, but I would appreciate any thoughts.

Also please let me know if any more detail is needed!